# How to return fragment_title correctly?ActivityMain error using DataBinding

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I know that this question has been answered 100 times but my code just doesn't work and I can't figure out what is wrong with it by reading posts made by others.

I want to make an app where when you open it u get a search filed, you tipe what u want to search and then click enter and you get what you searched for.

So, I'm trying to use DataBinding for that. In the activity xml file i wrapped everything with the layout tag :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

<layout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<fragment
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/TitleFragment"

    />
```

</layout

And here is my MainActivty:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    @Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

}

and my TitleFragment:

```
class TitleFragment : Fragment() {
//Inflating and Returning the View with DataBindingUtil

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_title, container, false)
}
```

}

I just want to be able to open the app with the fragment_title.xml showing via the activity_main as i want to use databinding for opening my views.
I keep getting the error "Unresolved reference: ActivityMainBinding" but in the build.gradle i included
databinding=true

viewbinding=true

but nothing works.
How do i fix this error and did i even return the fragment correctly?

Answer (score 0):

TitleFragment

```
private var _binding: FragmentTitleBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
//...this is code ...
return binding.root
}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityDoctorHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
}
```

Comment: You will write the objects you added in the fragment in TitleFragment, and you will use the objects you use in the activity in the activity.